# when adding spring jars to the project,it shows warning

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring. I want to develop a project using spring. I am using eclipse IDE. When trying to add
spring jars to the library,it shows warning for every jars like this..

"C:/Users/Nithiya/Downloads/springjars/web/org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.  "

can anyone help me to work on Spring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse warning: XXXXXXXXXXX.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884818/eclipse-warning-xxxxxxxxxxx-jar-will-not-be-exported-or-published-runtime-clas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library should be placed in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder. But you should better go with a dependency management system like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). The [Spring guides](http://spring.io/guides) also show you, how to add the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

suggest you use maven + grails.and the IDE is STS or GGTS,this is the effecient tools for web development, and STS is short for spring tool site,it is intergate with eclipse.GGTS is the high level STS.