# Copying a workspace from another user profile in eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

**I have tried importing a workspace from another user profile in eclipse. Every jar file is pointing to the user profile. Can i change the paths of the JAR's to my profile ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is nothing you can do except change the path's of the JAR files manually one by one.

To prevent this happening in the future, it is recommended that you keep dependencies inside a folder named `lib` inside your project or use a dependency manager.

Comment: I have added them now. now i am getting an error saying: Description 
The project was not built due to "Could not write file: U:\workspace\project1\bin.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

Comment: That means you do not have the permissions to write to that folder or it does not exist, first, try creating that folder if it does not already exist and then check if you have read + write permissions to it.

Comment: Thanks... that worked out. I have many warnings for adding the jar's:            
Classpath entry C:/Users/jai_imageio.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   

how can i solve these warnings ?

Comment: Now is the time to use StackOverflow's search function :)! Try this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884818/eclipse-warning-xxxxxxxxxxx-jar-will-not-be-exported-or-published-runtime-clas

Comment: No problem, remember to mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the project use Maven or some other build tool? If so, just delete the Eclipse files/directories such as .project, .classpath, and .settings and import.

Otherwise, try exporting the project from the old workspace, though you may have to manually add the Libraries afterwards

Comment: I dont know whether the previous user has used Maven or not? I have just copied his workspace. Is there any way i can find that ?

Answer (score 0):

Click Import and then choose "General" -> "Existing Projects into Workspace" and search the Directory.

If that doesn't work, you have lost some files. Then simply click Import and then "General" -> "File System" and search the main folder.

Hope I could help you.